# twitter Integration in ios 6 and Google Integration in ios 6 app

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, ios6, integration

Is there any tutorial to integrate my iOS 6 app with Twitter and Google. I have searched a lot but I could not find any good example or code. Please anyone guide me.

Comment: Is this using XCode? Or is this a web app? By Google do you mean Google Plus? Just Twitter or also Facebook? Have you looked into the universal sharing in iOS 6?

Comment: its only google and twitter not google+. I already built demo for facebook

Comment: Try this: http://www.getsharekit.com/

Comment: This is third party tool. I need to use twitter.framework classes to do my work.

Comment: only in io6 not in ios 5

Comment: The solution which i found till now is we must login in Iphone settings and then use twitter in my app. what if i want to login in twitter app not in Iphone settings

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for twitter in iOS 5,6.

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from my own app! :)"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```