# how to post on facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, post, facebook-login

I am developing ios app in which i need to login in social networks. I configured facebook in app i need a posting method using facebook login in my app note i already find a method of posting by login through iphone settings.But i need to post by facebook of my app.

not like this it is using iphone settings i need to hit facebook through my app and post through that login
http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/10/03/how-to-connect-facebook-to-the-ios-6-notification-center/

Comment: Have you looked into the facebook SDK?? They provide all the code and samples you need for this.

Comment: i had done with it. It is publish feed section. my work complete thanks

Comment: now similarly i want twitter integration not using device login see below link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050554/twitter-integration-in-ios-6-and-goole-integration-in-ios-6-app#comment19429788_14050554

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but twitter has an SDK too:-)